# How do you use the ContextFlyout with a ListView?

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-universal

I am trying to add a MenuFlyout to my UWP app for supporting a controller. The problem is that I can't figure out how to determine which ListViewItem actually triggered the event.

CodeBehind

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        this.DataContext = new List<String>{ "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"};
    }

    private void ChoiceA_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // What was clicked?
    }
}
```

XAML

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="ContextFlyout">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <MenuFlyout>
                            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Choice A" Click="ChoiceA_Click" />
                            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Choice B" />
                        </MenuFlyout>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ListView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested your code with Local machine and Mobile emulator, your `MenuFlyout` can be shown only on PC by right tapped on the `ListView`, then here is a solution, you can find the `OriginalSource` in the `RightTapped` event of `ListView`, then get the `DataContext` of this `OriginalSource` for example like this:

```
private FrameworkElement originalSource;
private void ChoiceA_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var itemdatacontext = originalSource.DataContext;
}

private void ListView_RightTapped(object sender, RightTappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    originalSource = (FrameworkElement)e.OriginalSource;
}
```

Comment: This does work for a right tap, but the menu button on the xbox controller doesn't trigger the event.

Comment: Using your example I figured out you could get the focused item using the FocusManager. On the GotFocus event for the Page  

    private void Page_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
            if (FocusManager.GetFocusedElement() as ListViewItem != null)
            {
                // Do stuff
            }
    }

Answer (score 1):

Bind to the `Opening` event of the `MenuFlyout`. In the event handler the `sender` is the `MenuFlyout` itself. There you will find the `Target` property which points to the `ListViewItem`.

Based on your example your XAML could look like this:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="ContextFlyout">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <MenuFlyout Opening="ListView_Opening">
                            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Choice A" Click="ChoiceA_Click" />
                            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Choice B" />
                        </MenuFlyout>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ListView>
```

Your code behind goes like this:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        this.DataContext = new List<String>{ "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"};
    }

    private string ListViewItemString;

    private void ChoiceA_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // What was clicked?
        var clickedItem = ListViewItemString;
    }

    private void ListView_Opening(object sender, object e)
    {
        ListViewItemString = ((sender as MenuFlyout)?.Target as ListViewItem)?.Content as string;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution. First at all, you need to modify your XAML, because the class ListViewItem doesn't have the property ContextFlyout. You need to use FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout inside ItemTemplate.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Tapped="TextBlock_Tapped">
                <FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
                    <MenuFlyout>
                        <MenuFlyoutItem Text="{Binding}" IsHitTestVisible="False" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="24" />
                        <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Choice A" Click="MenuFlyoutItem_Click" />
                        <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Choice B" />
                    </MenuFlyout>
                </FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Here the code-behind:

public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = new List { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3" };
        }

```
    private async void MenuFlyoutItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var fe = sender as FrameworkElement;
        var value = fe.DataContext.ToString();
        await new MessageDialog(value).ShowAsync();
    }

    private void TextBlock_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var fe = sender as FrameworkElement;
        var menu = Flyout.GetAttachedFlyout(fe);
        menu.ShowAt(fe);
    }
}
```

You need to detect the ItemTapped event of every single item inside the ListView, so you can show the menu.

Comment: ContextFlyout was added to the Windows 10 SDK 10.0.14393.0  
  
https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.contextflyout.aspx